# Can't select any image from system image picker

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-activity, permissions

So I implemented code to let me pick images from my filesystem using the default image picker in Android, but for some reason every image is greyed out. It's not letting me choose an image at all. I tested it on Marshmallow 6.0.1 (from where screenshot is taken) and on Lollipop 5.1.1.

[image]

Here's my implementation:

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.company.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Note that all of this has been done on the same activity, LaunchActivity.java

Variables as used:

```
private ImageView picturebutton;
private Bitmap imageBitmap;
final private int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE=1;
private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
```

ImageView acting as button:

```
picturebutton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.chose_picture);
View.OnClickListener picturebuttonClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkStorageReadPermission(LaunchActivity.this);
        }
    };
    picturebutton.setOnClickListener(picturebuttonClickListener);
```

The method *checkStorageReadPermission()* which requests for storage access permission:

```
public void checkStorageReadPermission(final Context context){
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(LaunchActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)!= PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(LaunchActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)){
        }
        else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(LaunchActivity.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }
    else{
        Log.d("Permissions","Permission was already granted");
        startActivity(openGallery());
    }
}
```

The override code for *onRequestPermissionsResult()*:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                startActivity(openGallery());
                Log.d("Permissions","Can read storage");
            } else {
                //code for deny
                Log.e("Permissions","Can't read storage");
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

The intent *openGallery()* which calls the image picker:

```
public Intent openGallery() {
        Intent og = new Intent();
        og.setType("image*/");
        og.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(og,"Pick a picture"),PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
        return og;
    }
```

The code to override *onActivityResult()* when the Intent is called:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(resultCode,requestCode,data);
    if(requestCode==PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null){
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        try{
            imageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),imageUri);
            x.uploadImage(imageBitmap,LaunchActivity.this);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

There is no problem with the permission requesting process, the system permission dialog for external storage access comes up, gets granted and the picker opens up, but I can't select any image. Help will be appreciated!

Comment: og.setType("image*/"); in place of this put  og.setType("image/*"); & remove  return og;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `startActivity(openGallery());`,just call `openGallery();` method. You are already launching the image picker in that method using `startActivityForResilt`, so you do not need `startActivity()` again. Also, remove the `return` statement from `openGallery()`.

Also, you are setting the MIME type wrong. It should be `image/*`.
So, the updated one should be:

```
public void openGallery() {
        Intent og = new Intent();
        og.setType("image/*");
        og.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(og,"Pick a picture"),PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**OnChoose Code**

```
        chooseimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {



            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){

                boolean result= Utility.checkPermission(getActivity());

                if(result) {
                    galleryIntent();
                }

            }

            else {
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                // Start new activity with the LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS to handle back the results when image is picked from the Image Gallery.
                startActivityForResult(i,LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS); //LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS
            }




        }
    });
```

---

**Also Code added For Permission and Set Image**

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS) {
                onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);

            }
        }
    }
    else {



                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && isMediaDocument(data.getData())) {

                    Bitmap bitmap = null;
                    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(selectedImage);

                    // Split at colon, use second item in the array
                    String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

                    String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                    // where id is equal to
                    String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

                    Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().
                            query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                                    column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);

                    String filePath = "";

                    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

                    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        //filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        mPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                    }


                    cursor.close();

                }
                else {
                    if (requestCode == LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                        // Let's read picked image data - its URI
                        Uri pickedImage = data.getData();
                        // Let's read picked image path using content resolver
                        String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(pickedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        mPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]));
                        //edAttach.setText(mPath.toString()); path set anywhere
                        cursor.close();
                    }

                }
    }
}




private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

    Bitmap bm=null;
    if (data != null) {
        try {
            bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
ivprofile.setImageBitmap(bm);
    }



    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && isMediaDocument(data.getData())) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(selectedImage);

        // Split at colon, use second item in the array
        String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

        String[] column = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        // where id is equal to
        String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().
                query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                        column, sel, new String[]{id}, null);

        String filePath = "";

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            //filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            mPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            //edAttach.setText(mPath); path set anywhere


        }
        cursor.close();
    }
    else {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        mPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex).toString();
        System.out.println("picturePath" + mPath);
        if (!mPath.equalsIgnoreCase(null)) {
            edAttach.setText(mPath);
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

}

public boolean hasPermissionInManifest(Context context, String permissionName) {
    final String packageName = context.getPackageName();
    try {
        final PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        final String[] declaredPermisisons = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
        if (declaredPermisisons != null && declaredPermisisons.length > 0) {
            for (String p : declaredPermisisons) {
                if (p.equals(permissionName)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {

    }
    return false;
}


 public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri)
{
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

private void galleryIntent()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),LOAD_IMAGE_RESULTS);
}
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                galleryIntent();

            } else {
                //code for deny
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

**Or Permission In your mainfiest.xml**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Utility.java**

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

public class Utility {
    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 123;
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    public static boolean checkPermission(final Context context)
    {
        int currentAPIVersion = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(currentAPIVersion>= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale((Activity) context, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                    alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
                    alertBuilder.setTitle("Permission necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setMessage("External storage permission is necessary");
                    alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                        }
                    });
                    AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
                    alert.show();
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot select one of the image in the list I think the problem is on the intent.

> The intent openGallery() which calls the image picker:
>
> ```
> public Intent openGallery() {
>         Intent og = new Intent();
>         og.setType("image*/");
>         og.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
>         startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(og,"Pick a picture"),PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
>         return og;
>     }
> ```

actually I see that you made a mistake here

> `og.setType("image*/");`

you should write ("image/*") or specify an extension like ("image/jpg") for example!

and actually you don't need for this operation of

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

as the ACTION_GET_CONTENT pick only the image Uri don't need for this permission